# netcdf query ocean temperature at different depths

Tags: geoserver, wms, sql, netcdf

I am looking for the best way to query a netCDF file - I would like to eventually expose this to an API to be consumed by a web service.

I would use SQL which I have experience in but I think its probably going to be resource heavy. I have looked into geoserver but I dont see any documentation on query this type of information only serving WMS tiles.

I have a grid of temperatures at different depths, I would like to for a given lat / lng find the nearest source (looking at just ground distance not vertical) of water at a certain temperature.  For example lat 30.083 / lng -14.5 find the nearest location of water at 20c.

My data has an array of data points for depths from 5 to 5000m the query will need to return the lat / lng and depth.

Comment: You can do that with a range of tools. If you've got a lot of it, load it up into a specialist store like THREDDS and do the queries using NCO or NCL (see https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/software.html#NCL and browse for whatever tools you like).

Comment: Thanks @BradHards I will explore THREDDS in more depth - it looks like a good too l to do this

Comment: surely a WCS query would be better than a WMS for this